# On an auxiliary lemma for the structure theorem on Dedekind domains

Tags: modules, proof-explanation, dedekind-domain

I'm searching for a proof of the following statement

> Let $M$ be a $P$-torsion module over a Dedekind domain $R$, and let $x_1 \in M$ such that $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x_1) = Ann_R(M)$. If there exist $y_2 \dots y_s \in M/Rx_1$  such that
>   $$
> \frac{M}{Rx_1} \simeq Ry_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus Ry_s
> $$
>   then there exist $x_2, \dots x_s \in M$ such that $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x_i) = \operatorname{Ann}_R(y_i)$, $\pi(x_i) = y_i$ with $\pi: M \to M/Rx_1$ the projection, and
>   $$
> M \simeq Rx_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Rx_s
> $$

I'm somewhat familiar with the lemma for principal domains, in which for a given $y \in M/Rx_1$ we first show that it can be chosen $z \in M$ with $\operatorname{Ann}_R(z) = \operatorname{Ann}_R(y)$ and $\pi(z) = y$, from which the ulterior condition follows.

However, the aforementioned construction uses strongly that if $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M) = p^mR$, then $p^m$ annihilates $M/Rx_1$ and so $p^my = ax_1$ for some $a \in R$.

My knowledge on Dedekind domains is very rudimentary so I would really appreciate if you could either provide a proof of this statement or a reference in which I could find one. Maybe the same be done for these type of rings? That is, if $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M) = \mathcal{P}^m$, can we find $p \in \mathcal{P}$ with $p^my = ax_1$? I think I could take it from there following the proof for PIDs.

Comment: Try to localize at $P $.

Comment: @FabioLucchini would you mind expandind on that a bit? Unfortunately I haven't learned about localization yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\ideal[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}\DeclareMathOperator\Ann{Ann}$Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $\ideal p$ be a prime ideal in $R$ and $M$ be a $\ideal p$-torsion $R$-module and $x_1\in M$ such that $\Ann_R(x_1)=\Ann_R(M)$.

Then $\Ann_R(M)\supseteq\ideal p^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, hence $M$ can regarded as a $R/\ideal p^n$-module.

Let $R_{\ideal p}$ denote the localization at $\ideal p$ of $R$.
Then $R_{\ideal p}$ is a PID, $\ideal m=R_{\ideal p}\ideal p$ is a maximal ideal and $R_{\ideal p}/\ideal m^n\cong R/\ideal p^n$.
Consequently, $M$ is a $\ideal m$-torsion $R_{\ideal p}$-module and hence the proof valid for PIDs applyies.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it. This is a lot to digest for me, since I'm not very familiar with these concepts. I'll accept the answer as soon as I get the time to give this a careful read, whether I fully comprehend it or not.